# Conditionally pass a prop to a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my component I receive a prop called *secondary* which I deconstruct, and If that prop exist I want to pass it to another component, otherwise no:

```
...
render() {
      const { yAxis, mandatory, secondary, quantity } = this.props
...
return (
      <View>
        {secondary ? (
          <MyChart
            selectedMandatory={selectedMandatory}
            yAxis={yAxis}
            mandatory={{ ...mandatory, label: labelMandatory }}
            secondary={{ ...secondary, label: labelSecondary }}
            quantity={quantity}
          />
        ) : (
          <MyChart
            selectedMandatory
            yAxis={yAxis}
            mandatory={{ ...mandatory, label: labelMandatory }}
            quantity={quantity}
          />
        )}
       </View>
   ...
```

Is there another (simpler) way to do this?

Comment: one possible way: `const secondaryProp = secondary ? {{ ...secondary, label: labelSecondary }} : {};`, then `<MyChart {...secondaryProp} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fix/hack it like this:

```
render() {

    var extraProps = {};

    if(secondary) {
        extraProps['secondary'] = { ...secondary, label: labelSecondary } 
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <MyChart
                selectedMandatory={selectedMandatory}
                yAxis={yAxis}
                mandatory={{ ...mandatory, label: labelMandatory }}
                quantity={quantity}
                {...extraProps}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

That way `props.hasOwnProperty('secondary')` will be false if `secondary` is not defined.

You could even pass in all props as a variable if that's more readable for you:

```
render() {
    var allProps = {
        selectedMandatory: selectedMandatory,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        mandatory: { ...mandatory, label: labelMandatory },
        quantity: quantity
    };

    if(secondary) {
        allProps['secondary'] = { ...secondary, label: labelSecondary } 
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <MyChart
                {...allProps}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sam. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You could put your ternary condition inside your prop definition, if your variable is falsy, `undefined` will be sent, and your prop will not be accessible :

```
<View>
    <MyChart
        selectedMandatory={selectedMandatory}
        yAxis={yAxis}
        mandatory={{ ...mandatory, label: labelMandatory }}
        secondary={secondary ? { ...secondary, label: labelSecondary } : undefined}
        quantity={quantity}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: but in `MyChart` component: `props.hasOwnProperty('secondary')` will be true.

Comment: @MayankShukla does that matter?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it may not be a good design, but one example of where this matters is for some third party components; namely, Ant Design's checkbox which will use the `checked` property to switch between controlled and uncontrolled mode. Passing in `undefined` will puts this control into controlled mode.

Comment: Thanks, man. `undefined` is the correct answer